# How to label several plots that put together by "Show" command?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeled

I created 4 set of the 15 plots by using "Table" command, then I put this plots together by "Show" command in way that first plot of each set being showed in the same plot, second plots of each set together and so on, I used "Table" again for tis part. Right now I need to add "lineLegend" to finial result. I tried different method but none of them worked. Below you can see part of my code. I can not share the original data here. test is list of list of list. I can add "lineLegend" to the induvial plot in this part of the code (graph = Table[...) but when I am trying to show them together I get error message. What is the sloution? And Thank you for your help. Below you can see one of the final plots, I like to add the "lineLegend" under the lines and it is better to be done by "Scaled" command as plots have different ranges. .

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
  Table[Table[EmpiricalDistribution[test[[k]][[i]]], {i, 1, 15}], {k, 
    1, Length[test]}];
colaor = {Orange, Black, Blue, RGBColor[0.22, 0.41, 0.23]};
graph = Table[
   Table[{DiscretePlot[
      CDF[\[ScriptCapitalD][[m]][[j]], x], {x, Min[test[[m]][[j]]], 
       Max[test[[m]][[j]]], .01}, FillingStyle -> White, 
      PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.008], colaor[[m]]}, 
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True
      ]}, {j, 1, Length[\[ScriptCapitalD][[m]]]}], {m, 1, 
    Length[\[ScriptCapitalD]]}];

tickH = {Range[0, 8, 1], Range[0, 8, 1], Range[0, 9, 1], 
   Range[0, 5, 1], Range[0, 12, 1], Range[0, 7, 1], Range[0, 7, 1], 
   Range[0, 10, 1], Range[0, 9, 1], Range[0, 8, 1], Range[0, 10, 1], 
   Range[0, 7, 1], Range[0, 4, 1], Range[0, 3, 1], Range[0, 24, 2]};
tickV = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
headings = {"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5", 
   "Type 6", "Type 7", "Type 8", "Type 9", "Type 10", "Type 11", 
   "Type 12", "Type 13", "Type 14", "Type 15"};
SN = {100, 1000, 5000, 10000};

Table[Show[graph[[1]][[i]], graph[[2]][[i]], graph[[3]][[i]], 
  graph[[4]][[i]],
  AspectRatio -> 1
  , FrameTicks -> {{tickV, None}, {tickH[[i]], None}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[30, Thickness[0.01]],
  
  FrameLabel -> {{"ECDF", None}, {"Number of Cells", headings[[i]]}},
  ImageSize -> 600, PlotRange -> All
  ], {i, 1, 15}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please use `Quit[]` to quit kernel. Then copy and paste your code from this web page into a new Mathematica notebook and evaluate it (on a fresh kernel without evaluating any other notebook). Have you explored `GraphicsGrid` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide a minimal **working** example, I will provide my own.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

colaor = {Orange, Black, Blue, RGBColor[0.22, 0.41, 0.23]};
SN = {100, 1000, 5000, 10000};

Legended[
 Show[
  Plot[Tooltip[#[[1]]], {x, 0, 1.5},
     PlotStyle -> #[[2]]] & /@
   Transpose[{x^Range[4], colaor}]],
 Placed[LineLegend[colaor, SN], {0.2, 0.75}]]
```

[image]

Comment: "Since you did not provide a minimal **working** example, I will provide my own." sassing like a boss!!!